# User is being sporadically logged out (only happens in Chrome)

Tags: php, jquery, session

Using a script I've previously used to start and store a session, except, instead of the user entering a password, I am using their windows login username and checking if they already exist in the user table.

On the index.php page, here is how I'm capturing the Windows login:

```
<form>
  <h3><?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; ?></h3>
  <input type="hidden" id="winUser" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; ?>" />
  <button type="button" id="loginSubmit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery to capture the the winUser ID:

```
$('#loginSubmit').on('click', function()
{
  var winUser = $('#winUser').val();
  $.post('windowsUserCheck.php', {winUser:winUser}, function(data)
  {
    if(data.indexOf("Error") >= 0)
    {
      $('#errorModal').modal('show');
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      location.href = "home.php";
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the process called windowsUserCheck.php:

```
<?php
include("include/sessions.php");

if(isset($_POST['winUser']))
{
  $windowsusername = $_POST['winUser'];

  $sql = 'SELECT `uid`, `username`, `fullname`, `department`, `email`, `password`, `userlevel` FROM users WHERE `username` = :username';

  $sth = $dbc->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
  $sth->execute(array(':username' => $windowsusername));

  $res = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $numrows = count($res);

  if($res[0])
  {
    $_SESSION['user']['uid'] = $res[0]['uid'];
    $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $res[0]['username'];
    $_SESSION['user']['department'] = $res[0]['department'];
    $_SESSION['user']['fullname'] = $res[0]['fullname'];
    $_SESSION['user']['email'] = $res[0]['email'];
    $_SESSION['user']['userlevel'] = $res[0]['userlevel'];

    echo "Success";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Error";
  }
}
?>
```

And here is sessions.php:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){session_start();}  

  include("connection.php");

  $id = $_SESSION['user']['uid'];
  $username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
  $department = $_SESSION['user']['department'];
  $fullname = $_SESSION['user']['fullname'];
  $useremail = $_SESSION['user']['email'];
  $userlevel = $_SESSION['user']['userlevel'];
?>
```

At the top of each page in site, I have included some scripts that first check to see if a user is trying to navigate to the page without logging in.  Once they are logged in, I check if the username is ever blank or set to 'guest', and if so, log them out:

```
<?php
  include("include/sessions.php");
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['username']) || $username == ""){header("location:index.php");}   
?>
```

Using all of the above, the user can log in.  Problem is, when the page refreshes, the user is sent back to the index.php.  This leads me to believe the session is being cleared or destroyed, but I am not sure how.

Why might this be happening?

### Edit

I have discovered that this issue only happens in Chrome.  I can stay logged in all day when using Firefox or Edge.

Comment: Come on, now.  Why the downvote?  Is my question not clear?

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){session_start();}` < that line is checking if the session isn't set then start the session. What do you think will happen if the session *is* set? I will tell you: the session won't start. I am pretty sure of that. That is what Mark also identified. Enable error reporting on the 500 error I saw in a comment under his answer; it's a server error.

Comment: I wonder why you're using a multi-dimensional array on the sessions?

Comment: I am not sure why I am using the array.  Could be because I switched over to PDO, but I think I see what you're saying.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` inside your php files at the top and under your opening `<?php` tags. What error(s) do you get back? I also doubt that this has nothing to do with switching over to PDO. Usually, sessions are set something like `$abc = $_SESSION['abc']; $def= $_SESSION['def'];` etc. Where and how are you assigning those?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Your question about the multi-dimensional array made me take a second look at how I am setting the sessions.

Comment: Ok. Well, I hope you find your solution John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the problem:**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){session_start();}
```

You are attempting to read a session before you declare `session_start()`.

Reading from the [PHP.net documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session **or resumes** the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

You would need to declare `session_start()` before you do anything with sessions, whether its reading or manipulating, so simply changing this line to the following should work:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Should be unrelated, I don’t think calling session_start would cause a 500 internal server error

Comment: Well, I threw a session_start() at the top of the index page.  So far, I haven't seen any random logouts.  But I fear the log files will show an error pointing to two session_start calls.  If all works, I will mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: I think it would probably be good practice to make sure session_start() is always the first thing that’s called and make sure it’s only ever called from one location, like you’ve done in sessions.php, any other call to session_start should be deleted and replaced with an inclusion of sessions.php

Comment: No luck.  After adding the session_start() on the index page, it still logged me out after about 6 minutes.  I just don't get it.  I'm still testing...

Comment: Interesting, I’d say try to figure out at what point the logout happens, I’m on my phone at the moment so I’m limited to what depth I can look into things but if you can edit your question with more detail on your findings I can try and help workout what’s still going wrong when I get back to a computer.